# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when object released mid-function

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class with a property

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyObject *currentObject;
```

and a function that looks like this:

```
- (void)handleExternalChange {
    @synchronized (self) {
        MyObject *newObject = [self.externalStore getObject];
        //Business logic...
        self.currentObject = newObject;        
    }
}
```

I am seeing a crash `objc_msgSend() selector name: copyWithZone:` occasionally when i hit the `self.currentObject = newObject` line.

I presume this is because the `externalStore` released the object returned by `getObject` on another thread and by the time it got down to the setter it was gone.

Does this conclusion seem right? If so is there a recommended way to fix this?

UPDATE:

Here's some of the stack trace

```
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: copyWithZone:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018149ef30 objc_msgSend + 16
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000018149c2d4 objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy + 44
2   MyApp                                0x0000000100115cb4 -[MyClass handleExternalChange] (MyClass.m:117)
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001829ee22c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
4   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001829ed930 _CFXRegistrationPost + 396
5   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001829ed6ac ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 56
6   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182a5cb9c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1500
7   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018292fbf4 _CFXNotificationPost + 372
8   Foundation                           0x00000001834366bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
```

Comment: It sounds quite possible.  Can you make `externalStore` give you a copy?  (Or, alternatively, you can copy what it gave you.  Or use something like `@property (nonatomic, copy) MyObject *newObject;` instead of a local variable.)

Comment: `NewObject` will hold a strong reference to the object. Since it is `copyWithZone` that is failing I suspect that it may be something *inside* the `MyObject` that is being released.  You need to provide more information.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's what I originally thought re: the strong reference. If it is the case that something in MyObject is being released before the copy wouldn't there be something in the stack trace when trying to access that specific property rather than the instance's copyWithZone?

Comment: `copyWithZone` may just use `memcpy`.  You need to look for `weak` properties or perhaps implement `NSCopying` appropriately for your object.  I assume that `self.currentObject` is declared as `copy` - can it be `strong` instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
  MyObject *newObject = [self.externalStore getObject];
```

That method shouldn't be named `get*` anything, but that isn't likely to be the cause of the issue.  Nor is it likely to be a threading issue (at least not directly).

This sounds more like there is some state related to the `copyWithZone:` that isn't handled correctly.   How is the copy method implemented?   Specifically, is it correctly copying all state and bumping reference counts or does it try to cheat by doing some kind of a byte copy?

Comment: can you clarify `copying all state and bumping reference counts` ? shouldn't ARC be managing the ref counting?